# Create indented child rows in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to figure out how to create indented child rows under the parent, in SSRS report. I am quite new to SSRS, the group by function works in a different (and obvious) way then what I want.

I have a sample dataset as below.

```
Declare @Employee Table(Code varchar(10), Name varchar(500), 
Organization varchar(100), IsChild bit, ParentId varchar(10))

insert into @Employee Values('BR456','Brandon','XYZ',0,NULL)
insert into @Employee Values('CR674','Carolina','ABC',0,NULL)
insert into @Employee Values('ME230','Melissa','PQR',1,'CR674')
insert into @Employee Values('JR987','Jerome','LMN',0,NULL)
insert into @Employee Values('JO435','Joseph','IJK',0,NULL)
insert into @Employee Values('ME321','Meghan','UVW',1,'JO435')
```

Here, Melissa is child of Carolina & Meghan is child to Joseph. I am looking for below result. I could not find example matching this.

Is it possible to make this using some formatting options?

```
Code       Name       Organization
BR456      Brandon    XYZ
CR674      Carolina   ABC
  ME230    Melissa    PQR
JR987      Jerome     LMN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received answer from another forum. Posting here for useful reference.

[Answer by Qiuyun Yu](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7351ed1b-460f-4ccc-a57f-82933845d5dc/create-indented-child-rows-in-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices)

In Reporting Services, a recursive hierarchy group organizes data from a single report dataset that includes multiple hierarchical levels, such as the report-to structure for manager-employee relationships in an organizational hierarchy. In your scenario, the dataset contains all the hierarchical data, so you can create a recursive hierarchy group. Then format a recursive hierarchy group with indent levels.

Reference:
[Create a recursive hierarchy group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255243.aspx)
[Using recursive hierarchy group in SSRS 2012](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/860824/Using-Recursive-Hierarchy-Group-in-SSRS)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the padding options:
right click on the cell you want to indent, [Code] in this case, then
select Text Box Properties -> Alignment 
then, under Padding options, click the Expression button (Fx) and replace whatever is there (probably "2pt") with this expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!IsChild.Value="False","2pt","8pt")
```

Comment: Yes. that's what i was looking for. I have added the case statement inside select query itself to add extra space to the left in case row is child.